# Modifying innerHTML in nested get() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, asynchronous

I'm currently using the jQuery get method to read a table in another page which has a list with files to download and links to others similar webpages.

```
$.get(filename_page2, function(response, status){
    var data = $("<div>" + response + "</div>");
    var target_element = data.find(target_element_type_page2 + '#' + target_element_id_page2)[0];
    var container = document.getElementById(element_change_content_page1);
    if (typeof target_element !== "undefined"){
        var rows = target_element.rows;
        for (var i = 1, n = rows.length; i < n; i++) {
            var table = rows[i].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("TABLE")[0];
            var isFolder = table.getAttribute("CType") == "Folder";
            var elem = table.rows[0].cells[0];
            var text = elem.innerText || elem.textContent;
            var link = elem.getElementsByTagName("A")[0].getAttribute("href");
            if (!isFolder) {
                container.innerHTML += "<li class=\"mainfolderfile\">" + "<a class=\"filelink\" href=\"" + link + "\">" + text + "</a></li>";
            } else {
                container.innerHTML += "<li class=\"folderlist\">" + "<a class=\"folderlink\" onclick=\"open_submenu(this)\" href=\"#\">" + text + "</a><ul></ul></li>";
                var elem_page1 = container.getElementsByTagName("li");
                var container_page1 = elem_page1[elem_page1.length - 1].getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
                create_subfolder(container_page1, link);
            }
        }
    } else {
        container.innerHTML += "<li class=\"mainfolderfile\">" + "<a class=\"filelink\" href=\"" + "#" + "\">" + "Error..." + "</a></li>";
    }
}, page2_datatype);
```

This is working fine, and all the folders and files are being listed. But when I try to do the same thing with the folders (calling the create_subfolder function) and create sublists with their subfolders and files, I'm getting a weird behavior.

```
function create_subfolder(container2, link1) {
    $.get(link1, function(response, status){
        var data = $("<div>" + response + "</div>");
        var target_element = data.find("table" + "#" + "onetidDoclibViewTbl0")[0];
        if (typeof target_element !== "undefined"){
            var rows = target_element.rows;
            for (var i = 1, n = rows.length; i < n; i++) {
                var table = rows[i].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("TABLE")[0];
                var elem = table.rows[0].cells[0];
                var text = elem.innerText || elem.textContent;
                var link2 = elem.getElementsByTagName("A")[0].getAttribute("href");
                //nothing is changed in the webpage. The modifications in the html don't appear
                container2.innerHTML += "<li><a href=\"" + link2 + "\">" + text + "</a></li>";  
            }
        }
        alert(container2.innerHTML); // Print the html with all the modifications
    }, "html");
}
```

The second get(), inside the create_subfolder() function are not changing anything in the webpage, so no sublist is created. But, when I call the alert() function at the end of the get() function, it prints the code with all the modifications it should have made in the html at the second get callback. I believe the problem is related with the asynchronous behavior of the get function but I don't know exactly why. Any guess?

Comment: What is `"onetidDoclibViewTbl0"`? A varibale?

Comment: It's the ID of the table I'm accessing in the external page. I know it's not very readable, but I cannot change it...